# Combine Two Int32 Into An Int64

Tags: .net, shift, int64

Have Dictionary <Int64, byte> that gets used a lot.  I mean in a loop that runs for days in a big data load.   The Int64 comess from two Int32.   The byte happens to be the distance (count) between those two Int32 from many very long lists.

What I need to do in this loop is

- Generate the key
- If key does not exists in the Dictionary then insert key and value
- If key does exists and new value (byte) is less than the existing value then replace the existing value with the new value

Right now I am using straight math to generate the key and I know there is faster way but I cannot figure it out. I put shift as a tag as I think that is how to optimize it but I cannot figure it out.

Then when the loop is complete I need to extract the two Int32 from the Int64 to insert the data into a database.

Thanks

Per comment the math I use to combine two Int32 into one Int64

```
        Int64 BigInt;
        Debug.WriteLine(Int32.MaxValue);
        Int32 IntA = 0;
        Int32 IntB = 1;
        BigInt = ((Int64)IntA * Int32.MaxValue) + IntB;
        Debug.WriteLine(BigInt.ToString());
        IntA = 1;
        IntB = 0;
        BigInt = ((Int64)IntA * Int32.MaxValue) + IntB;
        Debug.WriteLine(BigInt.ToString());
        IntA = 1;
        IntB = 1;
        BigInt = ((Int64)IntA * Int32.MaxValue) + IntB;
        Debug.WriteLine(BigInt.ToString());
```

And the best key may not be an Int64.  What I have is two Int32 that together form a key.  And a value of byte.   I need fast lookup on that composite key.  Dictionary is fast but it does not support composite key so I create a single key that is actually a composite key.   In SQL Int32A, Int32B form the PK.

The reason I don't use a composite key is I want the lookup speed of Dictionary and to my knowledge Dictionary does not support composite key.  This is production code.   In the SQL table there is actually a third key (Int32 sID, Int32 IntA, Int32 IntB).  In this parser I am only dealing with one sID at a time (and sIDs are processed in order).  I started with composite key lookup to SQL (billions in a run).  When I pulled IntA, IntB out to Dictionary to process a single sID then load to SQL at the completion of each sID I got a 100:1 performance improvement.  Part of the performance improvement is insert as when I insert from the Dictionary I can insert in PK order.   The new IntA and IntB are not produced sorted by the parse so direct insert into SQL would severely fragment the index and I would need to rebuild the index at the end of a run.

Comment: What do you mean by "straight math"?  Please show some code to illustrate the relationship between the two int32s and the int64.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I added a simple sample of the straight math I use.

Comment: `Int32.MaxValue` is 2^32-1.  Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Please propose a better way to generate a key for Dictionary where that key is actually a composite of two Int32.  And then extract the two Int32 from that key.

Comment: @Blam: Both my answer and Bas's combine 2 Int32 values in a somewhat simpler-to-understand manner than what you've got. I suspect you were *aiming* for something like what we've got, but didn't quite get there. Do you have anything *against* just using the two sets of 32-bits entirely orthogonally?

Comment: @JonSkeet See update to my answer at the end. I am looking for the speed of a Dictionary lookup and from I can tell a Dictionary does not support a composite key.

Comment: @Blam: Right, so something like the solutions given would be fine, as far as I can tell...

Comment: @JonSkeet What do you mean by orthogonally?  Like Dictionary <Int32, Dictionary<Int32,byte>>

Comment: @Blam: I mean that each `Int32` *just* affects 32 bits of outcome - and those are distinct sets of bits.

Comment: Oh, that second set is sparse like 200 values.  A word only occurs next to a subset of the total words and I only am looking for distance of 20 or less.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you just want a shift. Personally I find it simpler to think about bitshifting when using unsigned types instead of signed ones:

```
// Note: if you're in a checked context by default, you'll want to make this
// explicitly unchecked
uint u1 = (uint) int1;
uint u2 = (uint) int2;

ulong unsignedKey = (((ulong) u1) << 32) | u2;
long key = (long) unsignedKey;
```

And to reverse:

```
ulong unsignedKey = (long) key;
uint lowBits = (uint) (unsignedKey & 0xffffffffUL);
uint highBits = (uint) (unsignedKey >> 32);
int i1 = (int) highBits;
int i2 = (int) lowBits;
```

It's entirely possible that you don't need all these conversions to unsigned types. It's more for my sanity than anything else :)

Note that you need to cast `u1` to a `ulong` so that the shifting works in the right space - shifting a `uint` by 32 bits would do nothing.

Note that that's *a* way of combining two 32-integers to get a 64-bit integer. It's not the *only* way by any means.

(Side-note: Bas's solution works perfectly well - I'm just always somewhat uncomfortable with that sort of approach, for no specific reason.)

Comment: FYI, the OP's updated question includes code that implies that it's not just simple bit-munging...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I suspect that's more of an artifact of "this looked like it might work" than a deliberate decision. Have added a comment to check though.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth That Math is what I am using today.  I am just looking to make it faster.  Moving the lookup from SQL to a Dictionary was big performance improvement and looking to optimize Dictionary or if there is a better approach.

Comment: Thanks, tested at the bottom, top, and in between.  See cosmetic edit I proposed.

Comment: @Blam: Yup, that's fine - sorry for getting things the wrong way round :)

Answer (score 11):

If you want to convert back and forth from Int32's to Int64's you can use a struct with explicit layout:

```
//using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct Int64ToInt32
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Int64 Int64Value;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Int32 LeftInt32;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public Int32 RightInt32;
}
```

Just set/get values from the fields.

Comment: Note that the sake of language interoperability, .NET naming conventions would recommend `LeftInt32`, `RightInt32`, `Int64Value`, and `Int64ToInt32` as names.

Comment: FYI, the OP's updated question includes code that implies that it's not just simple bit-munging...

Comment: Oh! This is beautiful! It simply makes me happy. Thank you!

Comment: That's really neat, thanks for this. A question : If, in constructor, I assign `LeftInt` and `RightInt` (from constructor parameters). Is there a way to avoid the "field (`LongValue` in this case) must be fully assigned before return to caller" compiler error message ? (other way than assigning zero to `LongValue`)

Comment: @tigrou I don't think there is any way, however if you set LongValue to zero in a field initializer or in the constructor there should be no performance impact, since this is the default behavior for a struct anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bit shifting to store two 32bit values in one 64 bit variable.

I shall give a small example:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 5;
long c;

//To pack the two values in one variable
c = (long)a << 32;
c = c + (long)b;
//the 32 most significant bits now contain a, the 32 least significant bits contain b

//To retrieve the two values:
c >> 32 == a
c - ((c>>32)<<32) == b
```

Edit: I see I am a bit late to the party, just wanted to check in VS if I didn't make a mistake :)